# Where can I find ADR (American depositary receipts) prospectuses?

Tags: united-states, adr

I read on https://www.fool.com/investing/2018/10/24/what-is-an-adr-and-how-does-it-differ-from-regular.aspx:

> ADRs are subject to additional fees that traditional stocks don't carry. These are periodic service fees or "pass-through fees" that compensate the depositary bank for providing custodial services. These charges generally run from $0.01 to $0.03 per share, but you'll be able to find the specifics in the ADR prospectus.

Where can I find prospectuses for [American depositary receipts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_depositary_receipt)? E.g., given the ADR [AXAHY](https://seekingalpha.com/symbol/AXAHY), where can I find its prospectus?

I unsuccessfully look at:

- https://citiadr.factsetdigitalsolutions.com/stocks/profile.idms?pageId=15&subpageID=151&cusip=054536107
- https://seekingalpha.com/symbol/AXAHY
- https://www.barrons.com/quote/stock/us/ootc/axahy
- https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/axahy

---

I have crossposted the question at:

- https://qr.ae/pNnNvf
- https://redd.it/fg6fhh

---

Answer from https://ibkr.info/node/1185:

> While the amount of this fee will generally range from $0.01 - $0.03 per share, the amounts may differ by ADR and it is recommended that you refer to your **ADR prospectus** for specific information.  **An on-line search for the prospectus may be conducted through the [SEC's EDGAR Company Search](https://www.sec.gov/edgar/searchedgar/companysearch.html) tool**.

Comment: SEC Form F-6 is the registration document for all ADRs. SEC Form 20-F is the annual filing by Level II and Level III ADRs. SEC Form F-1 is filed by Level III ADRs. These filings are available on SEC EDGAR.

Comment: @Flux Thanks, I wish the question was open so that you could post it as answer.

Comment: There is a [meta question](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2892/10997) discussing whether or not this question should be reopened.

Answer (score 1):

I found some tidbits of info from a quick Google (but not an answer):

The AXA ordinary share is listed on compartment A of Euronext Paris under the ticker symbol CS (ISN FR 0000120628 – Bloomberg: CS FP – Reuters: AXAF.PA).

AXA’s American Depository Share is also quoted on the OTC QX platform under the ticker symbol AXAHY.

BNY Mellon is the transfer agent.

---

I'd suggest that you check the company's web site, the Edgar filings and look for a filing at the French equivalent to our SEC (USA).